# How to translate field in Django filter?

Tags: django, ajax, django-models, django-views, translate

From the client I get values. They come in `Russian`.

How can I substitute them in the filter?

It is necessary either to translate incoming values ​​into `English`, or field values ​​to translate into `Russian` (there are translations already in django.po). Is this possible with `Django`? Or do I need to do something with the client?

**models.py**

```
BORROWER_CATEGORY_STANDARD = _('standard')
BORROWER_CATEGORY_PAYROLL = _('payroll')

BORROWER_CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
   (BORROWER_CATEGORY_STANDARD, _('Standard')),
   (BORROWER_CATEGORY_PAYROLL, _('Payroll')),
)
```

**views.py**

*request.POST - dict of russian values*

```
cps = cps.filter(borrower_category=request.POST.get('borrower_category'))
```

**settings**

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', gettext('Russian')),
    ('kk', gettext('Kazakh')),
)

MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'ru'

USE_I18N = True

'django.template.context_processors.i18n',

SOLID_I18N_USE_REDIRECTS = True
```

Comment: Filters are automatically translated in the djsngo template. Are you sure it is not translating?

Comment: I'm sure in this.

Comment: So far, I decided as follows. Removed translations from the values ​​of variables and brought them to a general register with translatable values.